# Why can I sniff unicast packets coming from a bridged VM?

Tags: networking

I have an Ubuntu VM running as bridged, meaning it acts as a separate machine network-wise.

I sniffed from my **host** for ICMP packets using scapy (which runs by default in promiscuous mode), and for some reason have been able to detect ICMP packets sent from my VM:

```
from scapy.all import *
p = sniff(count=5, 
      filter="host 192.168.1.37 and icmp", #my vm's ip
      prn=print_pkt)
```

and I got some packets from my VM. Why can I see these packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridging doesn't mean the VM gets its own chunk of the physical Ethernet interface. It's a software bridge – it works by distributing Ethernet frames *after* they have been received by the OS itself. (Of course, they aren't passed upwards to IP/TCP unless the MAC address matches, but they are still handled by the host OS at Ethernet layer.)

So because the OS *already has* the packets, it can simply give them to you if you ask (by enabling promisc mode).

This applies equally to both native OS-level bridging (Linux br0) and to VirtualBox driver-based bridging.

---

(However, in situations where you *actually* want to dedicate part of the hardware NIC to a virtual machine, that's also possible – you'd use the "SR-IOV" feature, which is usually supported by server-grade Ethernet NICs.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to configure it so that the OS ignores such packets even in prom. mode?

Comment: No, it would prevent the bridge from working. (And it would kinda defeat the point of promisc mode...) But if you actually want _scapy_ to ignore these packets, there are some other ways of achieving it.

Comment: (But I think it'd warrant a separate thread, with a more detail explanation of the original problem you're trying to solve or avoid.)